# Rails image manipulation that is similar to ActiveRecord queries...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Are there any gems out there that would make the following possible? Assuming that User is a model and the image is stored in a db:

```
user = User.new
user.image.Rotate(45).Resize("45x60") 
user.Save
```

Needless to say, this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=6ddk6c680muj4eu2vr54vdveb7#rotate via http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

Not as awesome as you indicated above but it will get you there.